# Correct Syntax, still gives error

Tags: php, sql, syntax-error

I am having trouble getting this to work. The mySQL statement works when i plug it in directly, and the $dbc is correct as it pulls earlier in the script. 
 
Can i have some help?

```
//gets the username from the users table by looking for given id
function findUserNameFromID($userID){
   global $dbc;
   $getUser_query = 'SELECT username FROM forum_users WHERE userID ='.$userID;
   echo $getUser_query;
   //Errors on this line:
   $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $getUser_query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
   return $row['username'];
}
```

edit: forgot error:
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>' at line 1

edit: here is the full page code:

```
    //gets the username from the users table by looking for given id
    function findUserNameFromID($userID){
        global $dbc;
        $getUser_query = 'SELECT username FROM forum_users WHERE userID ='.$userID;
        echo $getUser_query;
        $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $getUser_query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc)." ".__LINE__);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
        return $row['username'];
    }

    function findUserIDFromName($username){
        global $dbc;
        $getUser_query = "SELECT userID FROM forum_users WHERE username = $username";
        $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $getUser_query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
        return $row['userID'];
    }

    $getThreads_query = "SELECT * FROM forum_threads ORDER BY lastTime, id";

    $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $getThreads_query);

    // show the data
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
       echo "<p>";
       echo $row['title']."<br />";
       echo "Created by ".findUserNameFromID($row['creatorUserID']."<br />");
       //echo "Created on ".$row['createDate'];
       echo "</p>";

    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the query look like and what is the error?

Comment: Whats the error? is $userID an int value in db or a varchar string? plus you may have sql injection

Comment: Is `$userID`/`userID` a number column or does it need quoting?

Comment: are you really sure about that? Use `userID ='.(int)$userID;` instead to check if that works. And are you sure that is the query that results in an error? Does not look like it, since you are not using `>`

Comment: Live page that shows the echo of the query and the error: http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~200220207/Web_Programming/Forums/index.php

Comment: Try `or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc)." ".__LINE__);` and see if that is really the line where it goes wrong. As you are not using `>` it should be in another place.

Comment: yep line 18. thats the right line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

The close bracket in `echo "Created by ".findUserNameFromID($row['creatorUserID']."<br />");` was in the wrong place causing the `"<br />"` to be included in `$userID`.

Note to self: Check where your brackets are.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be using bound variables, not embedding the parameter in the SQL like this (see http://bobby-tables.com/ for why not).

The error message you put in the question doesn't match the query, unless $userID contains a ">", which means either your message or your assertion that $userID is an integer is incorrect.

Comment: It would seem to be an integer, why the need for quotes?